# What is the compile-time type of the "throw" expression in C# 7?

Tags: c#, types, throw, compile-time, c#-7.0

In C# 7 it is possible to raise an exception inside an expression:

```
int n = list != null ? list.Count : throw new NullReferenceException("list");
```

In this position, the *throw* expression can substitute an expression of any type.

Now I want to define a function that executes some action before raising an exception:

```
??? DoSomethingAndThrowException(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Prepare for an exception!");
    throw e;
}
```

What would be the return type of such function, so that it can be used in the same places as the original *throw* expression:

```
int n = list != null ? list.Count : DoSomethingAndThrowException(new NullReferenceException("list"));
```

There's the option to declare it as a generic method:

```
T DoSomethingAndThrowException<T>(Exception e) {...}
```

But this seems cumbersome, as the generic type doesn't occur anywhere in the function body. Is this the only way to do it, or is there some type I don't know of, and which is assignable to any type (an "anti-object" type, so to speak)?

Comment: From the [Proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/throw-expression.md): *"A throw_expression has no type."* (and *"A throw_expression is convertible to every type by an implicit conversion."*)

Comment: No, C# does not a type like Scala's `Nothing`.

Comment: @UnholySheep - Thank you for the link!

Comment: You can keep your throw statement - check out my answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type you're talking about is known as [the bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), the subtype of all types, as opposed to [the top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type), the supertype of all types.

As you noted, the top type in C# is called `object`*. On the other hand, C# does not have the bottom type (though there is [a proposal to add it](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/538)).

Though there actually is one type that has implicit conversions to any other type: `dynamic`. This means that if you set the return type of `DoSomethingAndThrowException` to `dynamic`, your code would compile. But I don't think `dynamic` is a good choice here, because it's too infectious. For example, if you used `var` in your statement (`var n = list != null ? list.Count : DoSomethingAndThrowException(new NullReferenceException("list"));`), then the type of `n` would be `dynamic`, with all the baggage that brings.

I think this means that your conclusion is correct: generics are your best option.

* Technically, `object` is not the top type, because `object` is not the supertype of pointer types. But I think that's a distinction that doesn't matter much.

Comment: (Not that I'm the downvoter.) Conversions around `dynamic` are complicated. It's not that there's a conversion from the type `dynamic` to any other non-pointer type; it's that there's a conversion from any expression with the type `dynamic` to any other non-pointer type. There are a few places where the difference between a conversion from an expression and a conversion from a type is important.

Comment: @svick - Thank you for link to the proposal, I would be very much in favour of providing such a type. I also think that the proposed name _Never_ is very appropriate: expressions of this type _never_ evaluate, and functions of this type _never_ return. Thank you also for the idea to declare the function as dynamic, although I agree with you that it is inferior to the generic implementation, because I don't want the conditional expression to evaluate to a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that allows you to keep your pattern. The only change is that you throw your method, instead of throwing inside of the method. Don't overthink things!

```
private static Exception DoSomethingAndReturnException(Exception exception)
{
  // Do something

  // in the end, return the exception
  return exception;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
int n = (list != null) ? list.Count : throw DoSomethingAndReturnException(new NullReferenceException("list"));
```

Comment: This is clearly the right approach. You could even make it an extension method on `Exception` so that the syntax is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator won't compile unless both expressions return the same type or there's a conversion from one type to the other. So it doesn't really matter what the type of the `throw` expression is. Unless `DoSomethingAndThrowException` returns `int` or something which can be implicitly converted to `int` it won't compile.

The ternary operator is just for convenience, shorthand for an `if` statement. But in this case it's evidently not convenient, so there's no benefit to using it or writing extra code in other places so that you can use it.

This would be clearer:

```
int n;
if(list!=null)
    n = list.Count;
else
    DoSomethingAndThrowException(new NullReferenceException("list"));
```

Better yet,

```
if(list==null) DoSomethingAndThrowException(new NullReferenceException("list"));
var n = list.Count;
```

This would be even more explicit and clear:

```
if(list==null)
{
    DoSomething();
    throw new NullReferenceException("list");
}
var n = list.Count();
```

It may seem like splitting hairs, but cases like these it's often better to follow the typical conventions than to do something creative that works the same way. The execution is the same, but someone reading the code later could spend ten extra seconds trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: "The ternary operator won't compile unless both expressions return the same type." That's not true. There has to be a conversion from the type of one operand to the type of the other, but they don't have to be the same type. (So `DoSomethingAndThrowException` could return `byte`, for example.)

Comment: Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: To be precise you'll need to edit the last sentence of the first paragraph too. (I edited my previous comment - the method could return `byte` for example... and if it returns `object` then the conditional expression compiles, but the result can't be assigned to an `int` variable.)

Comment: Yes, I realized that right after editing the first one and edited that sentence too.

Comment: @JonSkeet To be extra precise, it's not enough that there is a conversion from the type of one to the type of the other. There must be an implicit conversion. There's a conversion from "2" to `int` but you can't do `int n = <somecondition> ? 1 : "2";`

Comment: Well, there's no conversion - not even an explicit one - between `string` and `int`, but yes, it does need to be implicit. (It can be user-defined, and complicated stuff can get involved, but it does need to be implicit.)

Comment: @JonSkeet `int n = Convert.ToInt32("2");` - explicit conversion from `string` to `int`.

Comment: No, that's not a conversion in the language specification sense of the word (which is how I'd certainly been using it - when discussing the finer points of the language, it's the only terminology that makes sense to use) - it's calling a method that returns `int`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess I should have quit when I was ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short [specification for the throw-expression feature](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/throwexpr.md).

The relevant portion to your question:

> The type rules are as follows:
>
> - A throw_expression has no type.
> - A throw_expression is convertible to every type by an implicit conversion.